# shell scripting remote commands through ssh

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I'm trying to create a shell script which will execute some commands which I require frequently. I made the ssh login to skip the password prompt using a public/private key pair. and after some search, I'm able to execute some codes like:

**File: ssh.sh**

```
ssh -X root@172.16.0.1 << EOF
cd /root/myDir
gedit a.c b.c
EOF
```

But I don't see any difference if I put like:

```
ssh -X root@172.16.0.1 << EOF
cd /root/myDir
gedit a.c b.c &
EOF
```

The `&` doesn't make any difference.With `&`, generally after executing gedit, it'll be sent to background and prompt will come. But I'm not getting the prompt after gedit. (Though whatever there in the next line is getting executed. Like if I put `echo "Hello"`, it's displaying `Hello`.)

What's wrong here? Is there any other method?
I want to do a SSH and execute some command through shell script. But I don't want to logout after the shell script finishes its execution. I want to logout manually after executing some of my own commands which are not repetitive like the above script.

Comment: What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: I expected with `&` I'll get the prompt by sending the `gedit` to background. But I'm not getting the prompt back.

Comment: That's because `ssh` gets `EOF` on `stdin`.  The connection is still open because `gedit` is still running, but the shell is gone.

Comment: @lcd047 Updated the question what I want and expect. Without EOF, I'm unable to open gedit remotely. As ssh gets executed, then when i logout, the rest part is executed locally. is there any other alternative?

Comment: Have you tried using `nohup` before the command?

Comment: Why bother with all this dance?  Write a function _on the server_, and run that.  Put `gedit` in background in the function if you must.

Comment: @lcd047 I want to copy paste some local code to a.c and b.c. So without opening them with ssh, I can't do that. After doing that, I may need to run some other commands. Previously I used teamviewer to accomplish the same thing. But due to some reason, teamviewer stopped connecting. So this is my best alternative.

Comment: @YoMismo Before which command? ssh or gedit?

Comment: @RatDon  as a quick workaround you can e.g use:  `ctrl+z` which will send a `SIGTSTP` to the process. Here after you can enter `bg`  and there you go!

Comment: @val0x00ff it's giving me a local prompt. not a remote one.

Comment: Then I suggest to run `tmux` on the server, and use a text-mode editor.  You can even detach `tmux` from the terminal and leave it running after you quit `ssh`, and re-attach to it later.

Comment: @RatDon before gedit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `&`, the script that you're executing remotely says “change to `/root/myDir`, then execute `gedit` and wait for it to exit”. The variant with `&` says not to wait for `gedit` to exit. Either way, the shell exits once it's executed the last command in the script.

If you want to execute a script and then execute more commands that you type interactively, you need to execute an interactive shell at the end.

```
ssh -Xt root@172.16.0.1 'cd /root/myDir && gedit a.c b.c; exec bash'
```

The option `-t` tells SSH to set up a virtual terminal on the server; by default it doesn't do that when you pass a remote command to execute. `exec bash` at the end tells the shell to replace itself by a new instance of bash, which will be an interactive shell (showing a prompt, listening to your commands, etc.) since its input is coming from a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `function` and then execute that over `ssh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh_func(){

    cd /root/myDir
    gedit a.c b.c
}

ssh -X root@172.16.0.1 "$(typeset -f); ssh_func"
```

`typeset -f` will display the functions defined within the script.